# spectrum of a unilateral left weighted shift operator on c0

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The spectrum of shift operators on $\ell_p$ is well-documented, however the spectrum of shift operators on $c_0$ does not seem to be nearly as commonly discussed.

**Definitions.**

Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ denote the usual basis of $c_0$, and define the continuous linear operator $T:c_0\to c_0$ by the rules
\begin{equation}Te_{n+1}=w_ne_n\;\;\;(n\in\mathbb{N}),\;\;\;Te_1=0,\end{equation}
where $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of positive real numbers with $w_1=1$.  It is clear that
\begin{equation}\|T^n\|=\prod_{i=1}^nw_i\;\;\;(n\in\mathbb{N})\end{equation}
so that the spectral radius of $T$ is given by
\begin{equation}r:=r(T)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{i=1}^nw_i\right)^{1/n}.\end{equation}

**Conjecture.**  Let $\sigma_p(T)$ denote the point spectrum of $T$ (defined as the set of all its eigenvalues).  Then
\begin{equation}\sigma_p(T)=D_r:=\left\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:|\lambda|\leq r\right\}.\end{equation}

**Discussion.**

The first answer below observes that
\begin{equation}D_r^o:=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:|\lambda|<r\}\subseteq\sigma_p(T).\end{equation}
(From this it follows that $\sigma(T)=D_r$.)  However, I need to show that $\sigma_p(T)=D_r$.  As this is not the case when $w_n=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (see the comments below), I suspect the conjecture is not true even for strictly decreasing $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

If necessary, we could make additional assumptions about $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ so that the conjecture is true.

**Note.**  I desire an operator with $0<r(T)<1$, so any additional assumptions we impose on $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ should permit this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point spectrum of your operator is empty.

Let first $0\neq \lambda \in \sigma_p(T).$ Then there exists an eigenvector $0\neq x=(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in c_0$ such that $T(x) = \lambda x$. This leads to the equations

$$ \lambda x_1 =0 \quad \text{and} \quad \lambda x_{i+1} = w_i x_i \quad \text{for } i\in \mathbb{N}.$$

As $\lambda\neq 0$, we get by induction that $x=0$, which is a contradiction.

Let now $\lambda=0$, then the equations become

$$ w_i x_i =0. $$

As all the $w_i$ are different from zero, we get again the contradiction $x=0$.

$\textbf{Edit}$: The above argument is wrong, I misread the definition of the operator. One can give a necessary and sufficient condition for the conjecture to be true.

The equations we really need to solve are

$$ \lambda x_i = w_i x_{i+1}.$$

Set $x_1=1$, then the solutions are

$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{\lambda^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n w_j} 
= \left( \frac{\lambda}{\left( \prod_{j=1}^n w_j \right)^{1/n}} \right)^n$$

For $\vert \lambda \vert < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \prod_{j=1}^n w_j \right)^{1/n}$ the solution defines a sequence converging to zero. Indeed, let $q:= \vert \frac{\lambda}{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( \prod_{j=1}^n w_j \right)^{1/n}} \vert$ then

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \vert x_n \vert = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \vert x_{n+1} \vert
\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} q^n =0.$$

We know that there cannot exist an eigenvalue with absolut value larger than the spectral radius. It remains to check, wheter all complex numbers of absolute value equals the spectral radius are also contained in the point spectrum.

One computes that $r=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} w_n$. Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$, then as the $(w_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing we get

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} w_k \leq  \left(\prod_{i=1}^n w_i \right)^{1/n} 
= \left(\prod_{i=1}^N w_i \right)^{1/n} \cdot \left(\prod_{i=N+1}^n w_i \right)^{1/n}
\leq \left(\prod_{i=1}^N w_i \right)^{1/n} \cdot w_{N+1}^{(n-N)/n}$$

Taking the limit for $n\rightarrow \infty$

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} w_k  \leq r \leq  w_{N+1}.$$

Taking $N\rightarrow \infty$ yields $r=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} w_k$.

From this we get the necessary and sufficient condition for the conjecture to hold:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{r}{w_i} \rightarrow 0.$$

An example of such a sequence would be $w_n=\frac{n}{n-1}$ for $n>2$.

Comment: Sorry I wrote "right" when I meant to write "left."

Comment: I'm sorry, I read right shift and did not read the definition of your operator carefully enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response---this is very helpful.  However, it appears to me that the omitted step in the argument is the most difficult. I do not see how to prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue whenever $|\lambda|=r(T)$. In fact, in case $w_n=1$ for all $n$, this would mean $r=r(T)=1$ and hence $|x_{n+1}|=1$ when $|\lambda|=r=1$ which is impossible for $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in c_0$. So, in that case, $\sigma_p(T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:|\lambda|<r(T)\}\neq D_r$. For strictly decreasing $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ however it may yet  be the case that $\sigma_p(T)=D_r$.

Comment: I fixed it. By suitable scaling you get an operator with the desired properties.

Comment: I am curious, why you are particularly interested in spectral radius between zero and one? Do you have a nice application in mind?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07428 . The structure of an operator lacking an AIHS resembles a left-shift operator by Theorem 3.6. It is known that every dual operator admits an AIHS, and so the natural setting to construct a counterexample to the AIHS problem is $c_0$ which is not dual space. It is known that such a counterexample must have eigenvalues for the boundary of its spectrum. It is also known (under certain add'l assumptions) that the spectral radius must be strictly less than the operator norm, but not zero. So this shift operator is the best candidate.

Comment: Very nice. Maybe you could include this in the question. Others will this find this probably as cool as I do :)